# How to code dictionary values to output hyperlinks to open local files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I could use some help. I have a text input that compares the input to the keys in my concepts dictionary and then depending on the matching concept or concepts this will list the corresponding files as a clickable link to open the files stored in the files dictionary. In this case, the files will be .py and will open Sublime Text. (in the code the files are listed as .txt but will change them to .py)

How do I get the files in the files dictionary to be clickable links to open local files that will be in the same directory as the script?

Thank you.

This my first time coding. My goal is to build up my collection and have a way to recall, reuse, grow and master my coding as I go along.

```
def print_big(word):
# use this to list python file and maybe a link to them to open
files    = {1:"http://file_title0001.txt",
            2:"http://file_title0002.txt",
            3:"http://file_title0003.txt",
            4:"http://file_title0004.txt",
            5:"http://file_title0005.txt",
            6:"http://file_title0006.txt",
            7:"http://file_title0007.txt",    
            8:"http://file_title0008.txt",
            9:"http://file_title0009.txt"}
# use this to change keys to simple keyword. 
concepts   = {'GAMES':[1,2,4,3,3],
              'BLACKJACK':[5,3,5,3,5],
              'MACHINE':[4,9,9,9,4],
              'DATABASE':[5,3,3,3,5],
              'LEARNING':[4,9,4,9,4]}
# choose more than one elements of concepts dictonary keys open more than one key value.
for pattern in concepts[word.upper()]:
    print(files[pattern])           
print_big(input("Enter Concept Idea: "))
```

Comment: Looks like you have two separate questions here: how to make text 'clickable', and how to allow multiple input words. You should pick one, and open a separate question for the other

Comment: For the clickable part - that has very little to do with Python and very much to do with your OS and terminal

Comment: Thank you for the critique and noted. I edited the question. So to create a hyperlink to open the files this is outside of python?

Comment: `files[concepts['GAMES'][0]]` == `"file_title0001.txt"`

Comment: thanks, I figured it out simply add "h.t.t.p://filename.txt" for the values in the dictionary. (I'll edit the code to reflect it)

Comment: However, this way only opens a new tab in my browser. I would rather have the software open (notepad for .txt and Sublime for .py)

Comment: Python has no way to check when a "link" is being clicked on in a terminal, so it has no way to act on that info. You could convert this to a GUI app (tkinter is the obvious choice, but not the only one) or even a web app, but either is *wayyy* too broad and likely considerably above your current skill level.